# Django admin site adding "city object" instead of "City"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a basic weather forecast site on Django and this error arises. I successfully made a "Cities" section but when adding any city name, "City Object 1" is added. This then creates errors when reading JSON from the API key.

```
from django.db import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=25)

    def _str_(self): #show the actual city name on the dashboard
        return self.name

    class Meta: #show the plural of city as cities instead of citys
        verbose_name_plural = 'cities'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import City

admin.site.register(City)
```

Answer (score 2):

two undersccore

```
def __str__(self):
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#other-model-instance-methods